# Max and min of $f(x,y)=e^x+e^y$ on $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: real-analysis

$V=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$ is compact and f is continuous on V so for Weierstrass global max and min exist.To find them I have used   lagrange multipliers but the system don't give a clear solution.

Comment: I have a wild shot... Substitute $y$ by $\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and put it in $f$. Then apply normal differentiation process to find maxima and minima. I don't know what this will result, just a vague idea to tackle such problems.

Comment: One can find the minima in a completely elementary manner - by AM-GM, $e^x + e^y \ge 2e^{(x+y)/2}$, with equality along the line $x = y.$ But trivially the minimiser of $(x+y)$ on the unit circle also lies on this line, and immediately we have that the minima of the original objective is $2\exp(-1/\sqrt{2}).$ Question: can the maxima be arrived at through some similar elementary method? I can't quite think of one.

Answer (score 1):

To find the maximum it is enough to consider positive values of $x$ and $y$ because $(x,y) \in V$ implies $(\pm x ,\pm y) \in V$. The method of Lagrange multipliers leads to the equation $xe^{y}=ye^{x}$. Note that the derivative of $\frac {e^{x}} x$ is negative on $(0,1)$ so we get $x=y$. Hence the maximum is attained at $x=y=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$. Hint for minimum: the minimum value will be attained when $x,y<0$.

Answer (score 1):

The contour curves $y=\ln (z-e^x)$ and the constraint circle $x^2+y^2=1$ are shown on the graph:

$\hspace{1cm}$[image]

The min/max of $z(x,y)$ will occur when $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Lagrange at all. Substitute $x$ and $y$ by $sin(t)$ and $cos(t)$ the problem becomes maximizing $g(t):=( e^{sin(t)} + e^{cos(t)} )$. Then $g'(t) = e^{sin(t)}cos(t) - e^{cos(t)} sin(t) $. Then $g'(t)$ then is zero iff 
$$ \frac{cos(t)}{ e^{cos(t)}} = \frac{sin(t)}{ e^{sin(t)}} $$
Let $ h(t) = t e^{-t} $. Then the upper equation becomes $h(cos(t)) = h(sin(t))$ . As $ h $ is monotonic increasing(as $h'\ge 0$ on [0,1]) the equation will only be true where $cos(t) = sin(t)$. So the equation will only be true for $t = \pi/4, \text{ or } 5\pi/4 $, or $sin(t) =cos(t) = \pm \sqrt{2}/2 $. So Max will be attained as $2e^{\sqrt{2}/2}$ and min as  $2e^{-\sqrt{2}/2}$

Comment: It is not true for $t = - \pi/4 $. $\sin(- \pi/4)={- \sqrt{2}/2}$ and $\cos(- \pi/4)={\sqrt{2}/2}$

Comment: Good catch! Corrected.

Comment: I think you mean $5\pi/4$ :)

Comment: You are so right :-)